# Fixed table header in <thead> using only CSS

Tags: css, html-table, css-position, tableheader

I am trying to get a fixed table header for thead without using Javascript. Here is the basic setup of my table:

```
<table>
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>...</th>
       <th>...</th>
       <th>...</th>
    <tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       ...
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried using css but no luck of achieving it. I got a fixed header but the width of it is small and it's not adjustable.

```
.thead {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: thead is not a class. remove . before thead in css

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<table>
   <thead class="fixedthead">
     <tr>
       <th>...</th>
       <th>...</th>
       <th>...</th>
    <tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       ...
   </tbody>
</table>

.fixedthead{position:fixed; top:0px;}
```

Comment: When using '0', a unit shouldn't be present (so in this case, it should just be top: 0;), besides that though, this should work.